# Depth map shows everything grey! OpenCV- Python

Tags: python, opencv

My code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

imgL = cv2.imread('Blender_Suzanne1.jpg')
img1 = cv2.cvtColor(imgL, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
imgR = cv2.imread('Blender_Suzanne2.jpg')
img2 = cv2.cvtColor(imgR, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

stereo = cv2.StereoBM_create(numDisparities = 16, blockSize = 17)
disparity = stereo.compute(img2, img1)

cv2.imshow('DepthMap', disparity)
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

When I run it, I see a window which is all grey? I think it is wrong. 
I used this code from the OpenCV docs website. 
Can anyone help?

PS: First I had some error which did not allow the output window to pop up. So, I added the two lines namely img1 and img 2 in my code.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is typical for depth maps… often, the data is still there, but it’s gray because all of the depth data is in the middle of the range, which is expected for e.g. indoor scenes when you’re using real units or a disparity map. In order to visualize the depth values better, rescale them.

Comment: @IsharaMadhawa and Dietrich Epp Thanks. I now modified the same code as on the OpenCV docs website. i.e. instead of cv2.imshow I used matplotlib. I don't know why that corrected the error. But it did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can display the result `disparity` using `cv2.imshow()` as well after you normalize it.

```
norm_image = cv2.normalize(disparity, None, alpha = 0, beta = 1, norm_type=cv2.NORM_MINMAX, dtype=cv2.CV_32F)

cv2.imshow('norm_image', norm_image)
```

[image]

Notice the change of data type after normalizing the image. Prior to normalization `disparity` was of type `int16`. After normalization it is `float32` (mentioned within the function `cv2.normalize()`)

Comment: Thanks :) This is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `imshow` use `matplotlib` to visualization as per the documentation. Also you can convert image into gray in the same line you read the image as follows.

```
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

imgL = cv2.imread('Blender_Suzanne1.jpg',0)
imgR = cv2.imread('Blender_Suzanne2.jpg',0)

stereo = cv2.StereoBM_create(numDisparities = 16, blockSize = 17)
disparity = stereo.compute(imgL, imgR)

plt.imshow(disparity,'gray')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks :) It is right but check out  Jeru Luke's answer too.